# How to achieve path based stickiness in Nginx?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, url-routing, nginx-reverse-proxy, aws-application-load-balancer

I am creating a meeting application, with scalability. I am exposing my application with an Nginx load balancer. The setup is in AWS.

A meeting is created on one instance only, and it can not be transferred to another instance or be partially created on another instance.

I would like the request from all my clients for one meeting to go to one instance (on which the meeting is created).

For e.g. [www.myapp.com/#/meeting1](http://www.myapp.com/#/meeting1) should always go to instance 1 attached with the Load Balancer and [www.myapp.com/#/meeting2](http://www.myapp.com/#/meeting2) should always go to instance 2.

I'm fine with using any other AWS resources or another load balancer like Apache etc.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set your hash by

```
map $request_uri $upstream_path_hash {
    default "nil";
    ~^/meeting(.+)$ $1;
}
```

Now, you can have your upstream as

```
upstream my_server {
    hash $upstream_path_hash;
    server SERVER_1:PORT weight=NUM;
    server SERVER_2:PORT weight=NUM;
    server SERVER_3:PORT weight=NUM;
}
```

Your location block would be

```
location ~ ^/(meeting)(.+)$ {
        add_header X-Hash $upstream_path_hash always;
        proxy_pass http://my_server;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the problem is, that the meeting can be randomly spun up on different instances. For e.g. it can be created on SERVER_2 and by this configuration, most of the requests will **almost always** be forwarded to the instance with the most weight.

Comment: Actually if you remove weights, it would forward purely based on hash

Comment: I do not understand this answer, could you please explain the code?

Comment: Simply use `server SERVER_1:PORT`. This will route requests to correct upstream purely on hashe of $1 which is anything after `meeting,`